# HTTP Post request with upload file and headers works from Postman but not working in python

Tags: python, upload, postman

if i upload the payload which postman send, it displays no files uploaded error, and whatever change i try to make to the code by adding a new custom payload displays the same error only .

```
@app.route('/Upload', methods=["POST"])
def upload(sql) :
name = sql["name"]
version = sql["version"]
url = "https://dod-orasenatdhubsblue02.blockchain.ocp.oraclecloud.com:443/console/admin/api/v1/chaincodes/upload"


with open('C:\\Users\\Ravi\\Documents\\chaincodes\\generic\\generic.go', "rb") as file:
    payload = file.read() 

    values = {
    'Content-Disposition' : 'form-data',
    'chaincodeId' : 'test30',
    'chaincodeVersion' : 'v1',
    'chaincodeIndexes' : '[]',
    'myfile' :{
        'value': 'generic.go',
        'options':  {
            'filename' : file ,
            'Content-Type' : False ,
            'type' : 'file'
        }
    }
    }


    headers = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
    'content-Type': "application/octet-stream",
    'Authorization': "Basic YXBpLnVzZXI6UXdlcnR5MTIzNDU2QA==",
    }   

    response = requests.post(url,data=values,headers=headers)

    print(response.text)
```

Error trace:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Mar/2019 20:21:41] "POST /blockchain/Upload HTTP/1.1" 500 -
* Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\Ravi\\Documents\\upload.py', reloading
* Restarting with stat
* Debugger is active!
* Debugger PIN: 903-210-066
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
{"respMesg":"no file uploaded"}
```

Comment: Can you post your full error trace?

Comment: @liamhawkins posted it ,please check it out and let me know

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is the error but you are missing the speech marks at the end of the url.

url = "https://dod-orasenatdhubsblue02.blockchain.ocp.oraclecloud.com:443/co

You can see the url has speech marks at the beginning, but not at the end.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake while uploading here, Thanks I updated here again

Answer (score 0):

Never Enter content-type

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
url = "your_url_here"

files = {
    "myfile": open("file_path_here","rb")
}

payload = {
    "chaincodeId": "id",
    "chaincodeVersion": "version",
    "chaincodeIndexes": "[]"
}

auth = HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'pass')

res = requests.post(url, auth=auth, files=files, data=payload)

print(res.content)
```